# ReactJS error in syntax at render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a react class but Chrome is throwing a syntax error in the render function.

I'm attaching the code here:

```js
var Chatrooms = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            loaded: false,
            pages: undefined,
            id: "-1",
        };
    },

    loadPages: function() {
        url = "/chat/api/chatroom/" + this.props.course + "/get/?format=json";
        request = ajax_json_request(url, "GET", {});
        request.done(function(response) {
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            oldState = this.state;
            oldState['chatrooms']=response;
            oldState['loaded']=true;
            this.setState(oldState);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        if(!this.state.loaded) {
            this.loadPages();
        }
    },

    render: function(){
        console.log(this.state.chatrooms);
        return (
                <div></div>
            );
    }

});
```

Browser is showing the error in line `<div></div>` as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`. I checked the syntax online and it looks good to me.

Comment: Are you transpiling the code from JSX to regular JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the JSX pragma on the top of the JSX file:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
```

This is tells the browser to use the JSX directive.

Comment: You shouldn't need that any more as part of 0.12.

Answer (score 1):

You must have used `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script type="text/jsx">`

Comment: And here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html for more info.